# calling UCWA with c# - lync 2013 server

Tags: lync-2013, ucwa

I sent a get request to below url (I replaced my company's real domain name with xxx here)

http://lyncdiscover.xxx.com/?sipuri=abc@xxx.com

instead of getting this format according to many blog.

```
{
"_links":{
"self":{
  "href":"https://lyncweb.sipdomain.co.uk/Autodiscover/AutodiscoverService.svc/root?originalDomain=sipdomain.co.uk"
},
"user":{
  "href":"https://lyncweb.sipdomain.co.uk/Autodiscover/AutodiscoverService.svc/root/oauth/user?originalDomain=sipdomain.co.uk"
},
"xframe":{
  "href":"https://lyncweb.sipdomain.co.uk/Autodiscover/XFrame/XFrame.html"
    }
  }
}
```

I got this format returned back without xframe (I replaced the domain with xxx):

```
{
  "AccessLocation": "External",
  "Root": {
   "Links": [
      {
        "href":         "https://lswebservice.xxx.com/Autodiscover/AutodiscoverService.svc/root/domain",
    "token": "Domain"
  },
  {
    "href": "https://lswebservice.xxx.com/Autodiscover/AutodiscoverService.svc/root/user",
    "token": "User"
  }
    ]
  }
}
```

what do I miss here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to update your Lync Server 2013 environment - [Updates for Lync Server 2013](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2809243/updates-for-lync-server-2013).  UCWA went live with Lync Server 2013 (CU1) and what you initially hit is the Autodiscovery service which was updated in CU1 to return the format you are expecting above.

The information was contained on the last paragraph on [ITAdmin-Configuration](https://ucwa.skype.com/documentation/ITAdmin-Configuration) documentation.

Comment: Was the server previously on 2013 as that is the only explanation for the older style autodiscover service response.  You may want to run %ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Lync Server 2013\Deployment\Bootstrapper.exe on all FE/Edge servers (the location most likely will be different) as I do not believe the Autodiscover service is correctly setup on that system.

Comment: yes, turns out we are not fully upgraded to 2015, some of the front end server are still on 2010.

Comment: That is really frustrating as you have seen if a user is routed/homed to a front-end on an earlier server they will hit this roadblock.  There is probably a way to guess the AutoDiscovery location, but building that into an application would be probably high up on the list of things not to do.